# How to setState() in React/Apollo with graphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js, react-apollo

I am trying to setState() to a query result I have from graphQL, but I am having difficulty finding out how to do this because it will always be loading, or it's only used from props. 
I first set the state

```
constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: [] };
```

Then I have this query

```
const AllParams = gql`
    query AllParamsQuery {
        params {
            id,
            param,
            input
        }
    }`
```

And when it comes back I can access it with `this.props.AllParamsQuery.params`

**How and when should I** `this.setState({ data: this.props.AllParamsQuery.params })` **without it returning** `{data: undefined}`**?**

I haven't found a way to make it wait while it's `undefined` AKA `loading: true` then `setState`. I've tried `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillReceiveProps()` including a `async function(){...await...}` but was unsuccessful, I am likely doing it wrong. Any one know how to do this correctly or have an example?

**EDIT + Answer**: you should not setstate and just leave it in props. Check out this link: "Why setting props as state in react.js is blasphemy" http://johnnyji.me/react/2015/06/26/why-setting-props-as-state-in-react-is-blasphemy.html 
There is more to the problem to update props, but some great examples can be found at this app creation tutorial: https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/8-subscriptions/

Comment: Broken link. Here's a wayback machine snapshot https://web.archive.org/web/20200125010920/http://johnnyji.me/react/2015/06/26/why-setting-props-as-state-in-react-is-blasphemy.html

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution is to separate your Apollo query components and React stateful components.  Coming from Redux, it's not unusual to transform incoming props for local component state using `mapStateToProps` and `componentWillReceiveProps`. 
 However, this pattern gets messy with Apollo's `<Query />`.

So simply create a separate component which fetches data:

```
...

export class WidgetsContainer extends Component {
  render (
    <Query query={GET_WIDGETS}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        if (loading) return <Loader active inline="centered" />;

        const { widgets } = data;
        return (
          <Widgets widgets={widgets} />
        )
      }}
    </Query>
  )
}
```

And now the `Widgets` components can now use `setState` as normal:

```
...
export class Widgets extends Component {
  ...
  constructor(props) {
    super()

    const { widgets } = props;
    this.state = {
      filteredWidgets: widgets
    };
  }

  filterWidget = e => {
    // some filtering logic
    this.setState({ filteredWidgets });
  }

  render() {
    const { filteredWidgets } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.filterWidgets} />
        {filteredWidgets.count}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the reason behind setting it to state? Keep in mind, Apollo Client uses an internal redux store to manage queries. If you're trying to trigger a re render based on when something changes in the query, you should be using refetchQueries(). If you absolutely need to store it in local state, I would assume you could probably compare nextProps in componentWillReceiveProps to detect when loading (the value that comes back when you execute a query from apollo client) has changed, then update your state.

Comment: Agreed, I found out that it doesn't make sense to use state, and to leave it in props!

Comment: this is the reason: Here is the "Why setting props as state in react.js is blasphemy" http://johnnyji.me/react/2015/06/26/why-setting-props-as-state-in-react-is-blasphemy.html

Comment: Cool, Apollo is makes things super easy!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (although it was happening for a totally different reason). My state kept getting set to undefined. I was able to solve it with a React middleware. It made it easy to avoid this issue. I ended up using superagent.

http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/06/05/redux-apis/

Comment: thanks Eric, I believe it was actually bad to use setstate. See: Here is the "Why setting props as state in react.js is blasphemy" http://johnnyji.me/react/2015/06/26/why-setting-props-as-state-in-react-is-blasphemy.html

Comment: Ahh. Yeah, if you just need immutable data, than forget setting props as state.