# How to use setState() with new <Query> component

Tags: react-native, react-apollo

I'd like to fetch data via the new `<Query>` component, but it's unclear to me how to get into the local state for editing until I'm ready to save the data again, e.g. finished editing.

This answer answers the question for the old HOC way, but leaves the question open when going the new components:
[How to setState() in React/Apollo with graphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457029/how-to-setstate-in-react-apollo-with-graphql)